# In Linux shell, have Ctrl-W / ^W send EOF when input is empty like Ctrl-D / ^D does?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, posix, readline

Is there any way to have ^W behave the same way as ^D with empty input in a shell? I use zsh, but this should apply to bash as well. It otherwise does nothing (if the input line is already cleared) and would this be uniform with ^W closing things throughout other UIs i.e. Gtk, web browsers.

Comment: So you want ^W to behave _exactly_ the same way as ^D? And do you want ^W to keep its current behavior? Because you can do `stty werase undef eof ^W` to switch which character is EOF.

Comment: As in `stty eof ^w`?

Comment: Trivial to do in zsh at least. But pressing ^W to erase several words once too many times and you exit your shell. Sounds like a bad idea to me. The fact that ^W closes windows in many modern GUI apps (and most of them won't let you rebind that) is to me one of the worst nuisances in those desktop environments.

Comment: I want the option to make ^W only send EOF when the input is empty (like ^D)-otherwise it stays as ^D.  As in `stty eof ^w`, but so eof works with either ^W or ^D. Is that too much to ask?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set two different characters to mean EOF. `styy` won’t let you do that.

However, that’s not necessary for this case. You can simply redefine Zsh’s built-in `backward-kill-word` widget:

```bash
# Tell zsh to call a function with 
# the same name whenever 
# backward-kill-word is activated.
zle -N backward-kill-word

backward-kill-word() {
  # Exit the shell if the command
  # line is a zero-length string.
  [[ -z "$BUFFER" ]] &&
      exit

  # Otherwise, call the original 
  # built-in widget.
  zle .$0
}
```

Read the [Zsh Line Editor docs](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html) for more info.